# Thread running slowly when created for the 2nd time (Java / Blackberry)

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm making a simple game, when it runs the first time it runs perfectly with no issues, if you complete a level the high score screen is opened (the run() method below), then the next time you play the game then it runs at about a fifth of the speed then first time round. I have another thread which is a timer which runs perfectly in both cases. I have looked through the code and can't find any reason why it would run slower the 2nd time round? Any ideas?

Below is the code that opens up a level from the menu screen.

```
    public void fieldChanged(Field inField, int inContext){
    final int level;

    if(inField == button1)
        level = 1;
    else
        if(inField == button2)
            level = 2;
        else
            if(inField == button3)
                level = 3;
            else
                if(inField == button4)
                    level = 4;
                else
                    level = 0;                  //Ensures variable is initialised

    game = new Game(level);

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(game);

    _invokeID = getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
            if (game.getActive() == false){
                getApplication().cancelInvokeLater(_invokeID);
                getUiEngine().popScreen(game);

                Dialog.inform("Final Score: " + String.valueOf(game.getScore()));
                hs = new HighScore(game.getScore(), game.getTime(), level);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(hs);

                game = null;                
            }
        }
    }, 500,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check your program java process JVM's heap / CPU usage statistics using jconsole / visualvm etc.
2. if JVM is doing frequent garbage collections then it indicates that your process is running out of heap memory and need to address the issue.

Let me know your findings.